# Android Eclipse XML

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I am developing this quiz but I have problem this design...

GuessButton.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/newGuessButton"
     android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:shadowColor="#000000"
    android:shadowDx="5"
    android:shadowDy="2"
    android:shadowRadius="5" >

</Button>
```

buttonshape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
android:radius="50dp"
/>
<gradient
android:gradientRadius="200"
android:centerX="35%"
android:centerY="50%"
android:centerColor="#5E0707"
android:startColor="#E80909"
android:endColor="#000000"
android:type="radial"
/>
<size
android:height="50dp"
/>
<stroke
android:width="2dp"
android:color="#878787"
/>
</shape>
```

Main xml where buttons appear :

```
<TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttonTableLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
```

xml code where Image appear :

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/faceImageView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />
```

For images to fit in all devices coz they are in asset folder.. in code I made this :

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.kuizi);
 DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    int h = faceImageView.getLayoutParams().height;
    h = width/2;
    faceImageView.getLayoutParams().height = h;
```

So in all devices I tested It works well... Here is a screenshoot :

[image: OKAY]

But On my friends phone is look like this :

[image: BAD]

So small image and bad buttons ...
I can not figure out why that... I'm searching on internet for a week and nothing found... can someone help me pls...
Thanks in advance...
I really will appreciate your help...

Comment: Could you please add the device information? What version of android is running on each device?

Comment: android 4.4.2 does not work on android 4.2.2 and some other androids work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm done, I made two Layouts, and at first one I fill with image, and second one I put all other stuff, so now the first half of screen is with picture, and second half is with other stuff,...

Thanks alot guys...

Answer (score 0):

It's some hard because you didn't post your entire layout... but try this approach please.

Try wrapping your image inside a `RelativeLayout`. In this case, the `RelativeLayout` should resize and adapt to the content.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
  >

 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/faceImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Another solution could be not using tables and play with `LinearLayout` + weight property. For me, tables are harder to work with but it's up to you!

I hope this helps!